# How do I count combinations whose elements are drawn from nested sets?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I have $n$ finite sets.  Each set is a strict subset of the next, i.e.,

$$S_1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \subset \ldots \subset S_n$$

I want to count the combinations of $n$ unordered elements where one element is drawn from $S_1$, one element is drawn from $S_2$, and so on.

Ideally, I'd like this both for the case where duplicate elements within a combination are allowed and for the case where they are not.

In other words, I want the number of $n$-sets (for the without-duplicate-elements case) or $n$-multisets (for the with-duplicate-elements case) $\{E_1,\cdots,E_n\}$ where $E_x \in S_x$.

---

For example, let's say I have the following sets.

$$
\begin{align}
S_1 &= \{1, 2\} \\
S_2 &= \{1, 2, 3, 4\}
\end{align}
$$

I can then draw these 5 combinations:

$$
\{1,2\},
\{1,3\},
\{1,4\},
\{2,3\},
\{2,4\}
$$

And, depending on whether or not duplicate elements within a combination are allowed, I could also include these two:
$$
\{1,1\},
\{2,2\}
$$

Note that the combinations $\{3,3\}, \{3,4\}, \{4,4\}$ are *not* counted.  Each of those is impossible to draw in such a way that one element comes from $S_1$ and one element comes from $S_2$.

Comment: Do you want to count the combinations of elements in $S_1,S_2\setminus S_1,S_3\setminus S_2,\dots,S_n\setminus S_{n-1}$? In your example, that would be combinations of elements from the sets $\{1,2\},\{3\}$.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé I don't think so?  $E_2$ can come from $S_2 \setminus S_1$ *or* it can come from $S_1$.

Comment: I am confused then. You say you want to draw one element from each set, but in your example you don't want to count $(E_1=2,E_2=1)$, where $E_2$ is an element of both $S_2$ and $S_1$. In any case, think about what you actually want to do for a low number of sets, say $n=2$.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé Sorry, let me clarify.  I *do* want to count $(2, 1)$ *or* $(1, 2)$ *but not both,* because I want combinations, not permutations.  That's where the strawman solution of $|S_1|\times\ldots\times|S_n|$ breaks down.

Comment: Can you give us a full enumeration for the two-set example you give?

Comment: You say order doesn't matter -- but then you immediately use an ordering in your final clause. Do you want to take all ordered $n$-tuples that work, then declare an equivalence relation via permutability?

Comment: @neoholopogon I don't have a very strong math background so my terminology and notation may have been sloppy.  Does the current revision clear things up?

Comment: Yes, your clarification is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Edited: This is answering a different question; I had misinterpreted the direction of set containment. If the $S_i$'s were shrinking rather than growing... so e.g if $|S_i| = n+1-i$, then there's only one way to choose all the way up.

Imagine choosing in reverse order. Let's write $m_i = |S_i|$, and I'll write $x_i$ for your $E_i$ because I can't stand element variables being capital letters.

Then there are

- $m_n$ ways to choose $x_n \in S_n$,
- $m_{n-1} - 1$ ways to choose $x_{n-1} \in S_{n-1}$, distinct from $x_n$
- $m_{n-2} - 2$ ways to choose $x_{n-2} \in S_{n-2}$, distinct from $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$

  $\vdots$
- $m_1 - (n-1)$ ways to choose $x_1 \in S_1$, distinct from all other $x_i$'s.

Your answer (if I've interpreted your question correctly: you want an ordered list $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ of distinct elements, where each $x_i \in S_i$ and the $S_i$'s are nested) is thus
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n \left(|S_i| - (n-i) \right). $$

Comment: The OP mentioned that $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ should be considered the same, so I don't think the list is supposed to be ordered. But the OP should clarify explicitly.

Comment: @Y.Forman is correct.  I've edited the question to clarify (I hope).

Comment: If $|S_i|=i$ for all $i$ and $n$ is even, the product here is $0$.